# Fermat's primality test and Carmichael number

Tags: java, math

I am playing with prime numbers and Fermat's Little Theorem. I read about Carmichael numbers and that they should pass the tests. The problem is, when I test it and use two different conditions it should end with the same result, but it isn't.

Code :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class FermatTest {
    public static boolean passesAllFermatTests(BigInteger n) {
        BigInteger testValue = BigInteger.ONE;

        while (testValue.compareTo(n) == -1) {
            if (!passesFermatTest(n, testValue)) {
                return false;
            }
            testValue = testValue.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean passesFermatTest(BigInteger n, BigInteger a) {
        //if( !a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        if(! a.modPow(n, n).equals(a)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(passesAllFermatTests(BigInteger.valueOf((long) 561)));
    }
}
```

When I run it with this condition, it returns true ( pass it ). If I run it with the commented condition, it returns false. It should be the same, isn't it? Is there an error in my code or I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when a = 3, your commented condition return false, it is because 3 and 561 is not relatively prime! Carmichael number require gcd(a,n) = 1 (please refer to the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

So in your program, you should first check "a" and "n" is relatively prime first before applying the commented condition.